# Entity is not saved when doing it via restcontroller

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem saving my entities. I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Flow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Step.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Step> steps;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ApplicationUser.class)
    private ApplicationUser user;

    public Flow() {

    }

    public Flow(List<Step> steps, ApplicationUser user) {
        this.steps = steps;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Step> getSteps() {
        return steps;
    }

    public void setSteps(List<Step> steps) {
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    public ApplicationUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(ApplicationUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Step {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String duration;
    private String description;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Step.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Step> dependencies;

    public Step() {

    }

    public Step(String duration, String description, String name, List<Step> dependencies) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Step> getDependencies() {
        return dependencies;
    }

    public void setDependencies(List<Step> dependencies) {
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }
}
```

My restcontroller has this method:

```
@PostMapping("/new")
public ResponseEntity insertFlow(Flow flow) {
```

With just the default save function on the repository

```
 if (flowRepository.save(flow) != null) {
                logger.info("Flow saved");
```

Now when I send this as post request:

```
{
  "steps" : [ {
    "id" : 0,
    "duration" : "test",
    "description" : "test",
    "name" : "Step 1",
    "dependencies" : []
  } ]
}
```

Everything is saved ( my authenticated user is retrieved in the restcontroller and put on the flow object before calling save )

Now when I retrieve everything or when I look in the database the steps are not saved. When I do it like this:

```
 Step step1 = new Step("test", "test", "test", emptyList());
    List<Step> steps = Arrays.asList(step1);

    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = (String) principal;
    ApplicationUser user = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(username);

    Flow flow = new Flow(steps, user);

    flowRepository.save(flow);
```

Everything works.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a `@RequestBody` annotation, that is why spring mvc is unable to properly recreate `Flow` from your json request body and just calls the default constructor (basically you get an object with all the fields left uninitialized).

```
public ResponseEntity insertFlow(@RequestBody Flow flow) {
    final Flow saved = flowRepository.save(flow);
    if (saved != null) {
        logger.info("Flow saved");
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, in the first case when you're trying to save an empty object hibernate just creates a new record for `Flow` and do nothing else.

But when you create your `Flow` object manually you correctly set all the fields, so Hibernate is able to successfully save it and all transitive entities.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot the annotation.